# Compare two similar Postgres databases for differences

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I occasionally download publicly available data sets in the form of Postgres dBs.   These datasets are updated/modified/expanded over time by the repository host.

Is there a Postgres command or tool (ideally FOSS) that can show the differences between an OLD and NEW Postgres database ?  (A working assumption is that 95% of the entries are unchanged and that the tables and relationships also do not change).

Comment: What did you end up using? None of the answers really seem to have a solution.

Comment: pg_dump each database and diff the files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the Stack Overflow Q & A, [How to check difference between two databases in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804779/how-to-check-difference-between-two-databases-in-postgressql); in particular [Another PostgreSQL Diff Tool (apgdiff)](http://apgdiff.com/) (schema comparison only). Apgdiff is recommended by Alexander Kuznetsov - a published database book author and bit of a guru.

Maybe also look at [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Compare Database Table Data](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metaqa).

There are also commercial products - e.g. [Altova Database Differencing with DiffDog](https://www.altova.com/diffdog/database-diff-tool.html)

Comment: apgdiff doesn't compare table data, metaqa is last released 2008 and is broken. liquibase's [database diff](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) is not geared towards the OPs use-case: "Data differences (limited), not checked by default"

Answer (score 10):

For schema comparisons, **pgadmin4** has a Schema Diff feature (in beta as of 26 Jun 2020).  https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: Is there a command line version?

Answer (score 2):

There is also:

- [PgDiff](http://pgdiff.sourceforge.net/)
- and the tool I'm working on [Postgres Compare](https://www.postgrescompare.com) which is free while in beta

Comment: pgdiff does not compare table data.

Comment: Postgres Compare is not free... even so it looks like that due to name of the section "free download"

Answer (score 1):

If you need something fairly quick and dirty to compare schemas, I wrote this [gist](https://gist.github.com/flbuddymooreiv/491d389aec7052ae9af9) to help compare a running schema to a "latest" schema -- something maybe hosted in SCM. It's working fairly well for a ~50 tables project:

Assuming a database *mydb*, and a canonical database file defined in a file `tables.sql`, here is a way to tell if an operational schema differs from the canonical one:

```bash
pg_dump -U postgres -a mydb > mydbdata.sql
psql -U postgres -c "drop database mydbcanonical"
psql -U postgres -c "create database mydbcanonical"
psql -U postgres -d mydbcanonical -f tables.sql
psql -U postgres -d mydbcanonical -f mydbdata.sql
```

The gist is to see if the operational database's data will load cleanly into the canonical schema. **These commands depend on the admin to visually parse the output of the last command where the data is loaded into the test database for errors.** If there are no errors of concern, the schema is compliant.

Comment: Does not compare table data.

Comment: That was okay for my needs. I only needed to compare schemas - the data inside was not as important. I'm sure it's not far from being able to compare data if you can somehow control the order of the dump to be deterministic across versioins/installs/etc.

Comment: It's okay. I was just frustrated that nobody had a good answer to the actual question sofar (Which specifically states "A working assumption is that 95% of the entries are unchanged and _that the tables and relationships also do not change_".)